# How not to choose blank rows in python?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, blank-line

I wrote the following code in python to choose only selected rows. However 'activity_url.csv' has blank rows. Hence it is giving me an error. So how do I skip the blank rows?

```
data = pd.read_csv('activity_url.csv', delimiter=';')
x="http"
url_data=np.array(data[data.iloc[:,1].str.contains(x, na=False)])[:,1]
```

Comment: Do you want to skip blanks or remove the entire row?

Comment: I wonder what the error says. But how about that solution: If you want to skip all whitespace lines, you should use this test: '   '.isspace()  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890688/how-to-skip-blank-line-while-reading-csv-file-using-python

Comment: The [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) states that `skip_blank_lines` is set to `True` per default. Hence, blank rows should be skipped anyhow. What exact error do you receive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python csv reader ignore blank row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508832/python-csv-reader-ignore-blank-row)

Comment: @Jokab no, as this is pandas / read_csv :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('activity_url.csv')
df=df.dropna()
```

After execution, you will get dataframe without any blank row.