# Reading from spreadsheet that is CSV and getting some unexpected empty lists

Tags: python, list, csv

SO here's the code -

```
import csv

with open('csv_example_files.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile , delimiter = ',')
    print(readCSV)
    for row in readCSV:
        print(row)
```

And the output is:

```
<_csv.reader object at 0x0000024D3DC42388>
['1/2/2014', '4', 'red']
['1/2/2014', '1', 'kv']
['1/2/2014', '1', 'jblock']
['1/3/2018', '1', 'kv']
['1/5/2114', '1', 'kv']
[]
[]
[]
```

I didn't expect the last 3 empty lists I don't know why they occurred so help me out. I am just a beginner and as I was following a tutorial series and I got stuck here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a copy of the `csv_example_files.csv` file you're testing with. Also, in Python 3 you should add a `newline=''` keyword argument to the `open()` call. For Python 2, you need to add a mode argument after the file name argument of `'rb'`.

Comment: If your CSV file contains blank lines, you could add `if len(row) == 3:` before your print statement to skip over them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting those extra lines as your CSV file contains blank lines. You can either edit the file and remove the blank lines, or alternatively add a test to make sure that the row contains the correct number of cells, e.g. `3`:

```
import csv

with open('csv_example_files.csv', newline='') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)

    for row in csv_input:
        if len(row) == 3:
            print(row)
```

This should give you the following output:

```
['1/2/2014', '4', 'red']
['1/2/2014', '1', 'kv']
['1/2/2014', '1', 'jblock']
['1/3/2018', '1', 'kv']
['1/5/2114', '1', 'kv']
```

Note: The delimiter for a CSV file is already a `,`. You should also add `newline=''` when using Python 3.x

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that your CSV file ends with 3 newlines. These result in empty lists when reading via `csv` module.

Answer (score -1):

Try add `csvfile.readline()`:

```
with open("csv_example_files.csv") as csvfile:
    csvfile.readline()
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile , delimiter = ',')
    print(readCSV)
    for row in readCSV:
        print(row)
```

Check this [**answers**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508832/python-csv-reader-ignore-blank-row/#answer-31508940)